# Prokka error message

Tags: sequence-alignment, sequence-annotation, software-usage, orf

I am trying to run Prokka but the following error message appears:

> Could not run command: makeblastdb -hash_index -dbtype prot -in /cluster/software/prokka/1.13.7-gompi-2019a/db/kingdom/Archaea/sprot -logfile /dev/null

When I removed the `--setupdb`, the following error message appeared:

> The sequence databases have not been indexed. Please run 'prokka --setupdb' first

after that, I changed my script to

```
prokka --setupdb --kingdom Bacteria -o $OUTPUTFILE.txt o- $OUTPUTFILE.tsv o- $OUTPUTFILE.tbl o- $OUTPUTFILE.faa o- $OUTPUTFILE.gff /cluster/work/users/ahmedbar/191129_M01132.Project_Petersen-DNAlibs2-2019-11-06/prokka_A_C/$SAMPLE_ID_1
```

and still not working and the following error message appeared

> Could not run command: makeblastdb -hash_index -dbtype prot -in /cluster/software/prokka/1.13.4-foss-2018b/db/kingdom/Archaea/sprot -logfile /dev/null

Comment: What is the output to `which -a makeblastdb`?

Comment: How did you install prokka?

Comment: It is installed by the admin. I work through the university server.

Comment: i think the answer to Ram RS's question will be crucial. what happens when you try to run `makeblastdb -hash_index -dbtype prot -in /cluster/software/prokka/1.13.4-foss-2018b/db/kingdom/Archaea/sprot` ? I wonder if you don't have write permissions to that directory, so it's failing. I would suggest contacting your admin, who will have a better idea of your setup than we have.